# Choosing between WPF, wxWidgets, Win32 API and MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc

Imagine you are on Windows 7 and you have to write a GUI for a GRAPHIC application, (like a terrain editor, mesh viewer ..) which involves a great use of DirectX and OpenGL (so written in native C++).
If your goal is a multi-platform software then you should go for wxWidgets, but imagine you're doing a Windows' only app...what would your choice be? and why?

I'm supposing that the application would work on both XP and Vista/7 and obviously in the WPF case the UI will be managed, but it will call native functions by a C++/CLI proxy-like class
( will "bouncing" from managed-native and native-managed cause performance issues? ).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[RAD Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio) can also make the job

- Enhanced in 2010! VCL (Visual
  Component Library) for rapidly
  building Microsoft Windows
  applications now includes seamless
  Windows 7 support, and graceful
  fallback compatibility with Windows
  Vista, XP, and 2000
- Enhanced in 2010! Windows Vista and
  Windows 7 API headers to fully
  exploit the latest Windows
  capabilities
- New in 2010! Support for Windows 7
  Direct2D API

you can also make WPF with [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism) and wxWidgets with [twinforms](http://www.twinforms.com/products/wxformscpp/index.php)

Comment: The OP mentioned C++, so it's also worth pointing out that RAD Studio includes C++ Builder.

Comment: Yes, that question seems to be calling for C++Builder and VCL.
OpenGL is supported out-of-the-box, and DirectX libraries for C++Builder can be found at www.clootie.ru .

Answer (score 12):

If you are comfortable with your C++ skills, I recommend WTL. It is very lightweight and results in lean machine code. The Windows version of Google Chrome [was written with WTL](https://adtmag.com/articles/2008/09/12/googles-chrome-browser-contains-microsoft-code.aspx).

Comment: not sure why this was down voted, it's a legitimate answer that wasn't suggested. +1

Answer (score 9):

To minimize development time and maximize performance I would definite go with Delphi 2010 (Rad Studio 2010).  You get native execution, direct interfaces with Windows 7 Direct2D API, and arguably one of the best IDE/Development environments available on Windows 7.  What else do you want?

Larry Drews
TheSoftwareRonin

Answer (score 8):

You might consider using Qt, even for a Windows-only app, simply because the Qt C++ API is so nicely done.  Qt [supports OpenGL](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtopengl.html#details) and can be used in conjunction with DirectX.

Comment: Does QT use Direct2D and DirectWrite?

Answer (score 7):

In WPF, you can actually use DirectX Shaders to apply effects on interface objects, ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFPixelShader.aspx)'s a CodeProject article detailing development aspects) and it is expected that the support for this will continue to grow, so I would choose WPF as a development platform. Furthermore, it focuses on creating attractive user interfaces with a reasonable amout of effort, and I think this is quite important in building a Graphics oriented aplication.

Comment: I've had horrible experiences with WPF rendering custom drawn objects using the visual layer. The delay is so noticeable. Same goes for Shapes and other UIElements.. So I guess WPF is really great for usual GUI stuff, but when it comes to rendering high performance stuff, there's no other way than go low level using interop..

Answer (score 2):

will "bouncing" from managed-native and native-managed cause performance issues?

definitely, but since you write just editor (not a game, in general) it's not a thing you should worry about

WPF applications rendered by DirectX subsystem as i know. so if you using only DirectX it will be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32-framework/ to create any Windows based applications in C++. Otherwise I would just use VB.Net or C# because you can easily port code between both and the form designer is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
MFC       :: Just say NO for any kind of project.
Win32     :: Well, I can not really recommend using it.
wxWidgets :: I have used it and seen no problem, good choice.
WPF       :: I have not and never will use it as it is .Net bound.
FLTK      :: Also look at http://fltk.org/, probably has better OpenGL support.
```

Comment: @Dan - this simply wrong. WPF is definitelly not the best option for *any new* Windows app.

Comment: @Robot Mess: IMHO, it is not even Object Oriented. It forces you to do things in certain ways. IIRC, there was so much wizard code in a MFC app, something that I hate. VCL was a much better library. Today, I only use portable UI toolkits...

Comment: @Malkocoglu: every gui framework foreces you to "do things in certain ways". I agree on the wizard part, I also would prefer a better forms editor.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out WDL ("whittle") by the Cockos team (headed by Justin Frankel of Nullsoft/Winamp fame).

It's an extremely lightweight C++ library that includes "WDL Virtual Window system."

I personally haven't used it, but I can vouch for some great software that's been made with it.  Extremely efficient and lightweight apps.

Link: [WDL](http://www.cockos.com/wdl/)

Answer (score 1):

I can't really comment on wxWidgets, but WPF is vastly superior to MFC and good old Win32 API. WPF uses DirectX for rendering and there are some [3D support in WPF](http://www.codeplex.com/3DTools). Unfortunately this support is still somewhat rudimentary and not the most performant. You can actually get better 3D performance if you host a Windows Forms control that renders OpenGL (at least we had to do that in a recent project I worked on). If you want to do 3D rendering in a WPF application you could have a look at the XNA Framework. The next version of the .NET framework will also include improvements to WPF and I'm sure there will be better support for 3D.